# How to test a child actor termination in a unit test in JAVA

Tags: java, testing, akka, parent-child

I have the following actor hierarchy

```
static class MyActor extends UntypedActor {
  public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
    if (msg is something) {
     childActor.tell(do something);
    } else if (o instanceof Exception) {
      throw (Exception) o;
    }
  }


static class ChildActor extends UntypedActor {
   if (msg is "do something) {
      //do something else
      getSelf().tell(PoisonPill)
    }
}
```

How do I test that when my parent actor recieves a message the child actor also receives a message

Here is the test

```
@Before
     childProps = Props.create(ForwardingWrapper.class, childProbe.getRef());
     childRef = TestActorRef.create(system, childProps);



  @Test
public void myTest () {
    underTest.tell("send parent message);
    childProbe.expectMsgClass(Terminated.class);
}
```

This gives a timeout at assertion, what am I missing?

Comment: Totally off-topic, but the title of this post is awesome. :)

Comment: why is that, btw I updated

Comment: "How to mock child actors"? Never mind, it was off-topic.

Comment: lol get it now, i guess now I'll attract the right audience